# How to stop onclick, onblur, on* from happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onblur

I have

```
<select onclick="alert('I was clicked!');" onblur="alert('Lost my focus :(');">
```

And I have jQuery listener that will click and blur this select if another element is clicked and blurred.

I have one problem and 1 question.

1. Why does onclick, onblur, on* gets fired twice when another element triggers event?
2. Is there a way to stop onclick, onblur, on* from firing?

Thank you!

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fallenboy/rUKyq/1/

### EDIT:

As it seems, it cannot be achieved?

Comment: Maybe you could create example to the http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

you can use preventDefault() function to stop the default behavior

Comment: preventDefault() doesnt seem to stop it.

Comment: Example $("a").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  });

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onclick="alert('I was clicked!'); return false;" onblur="alert('Lost my focus :(');">
```

or

```
<select onclick="alert('I was clicked!');" onblur="alert('Lost my focus :('); return false;">
```